# F-ratio in repeated-measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, interaction

In factorial designs with one random factor and one fixed factor, the expected mean square for the fixed factor does contain three sources:

the main effect, the interaction, and error

Therefore, to test for the main effect of the fixed factor, the denominator of the resulting F-ratio is not the error but the interaction MS.

Data from one-way within subjects designs can also be seen as designs with one random factor (subjects) and a fixed factor (treatment). Similarly, the interaction MS between subject and treatment is used in the denominator. But unlike the procedure above, it is not possible to separate interaction from error because there is only one observation per cell.

But how can one be sure then that it is indeed interaction and not just error variance in the denominator? Or do I get something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem clear what you're concerned about. You can get no error term (the interaction) with or without sphericity. What makes you think your second paragraph is necessarily true?

Comment: say Z is the sum of squares in the denominator. It then consists of two sources, namely interaction + error. If my prior goal is to divide by error sum of squares, then the fact that interaction is zero would be fine. Because then, Z would only be error variance. Apparently, it is not the error but the interaction one wants to divide by. But then, either if there is interaction or not, the F-ratio would not be valid.

Comment: It's unclear what error you're discussing but it seems that, minimally, you're confusing (at least in your relation of them) theoretical components of the error term and calculated components. Perhaps edit your question to be most specific in what you're asking because right now it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I edited my question. Hope it now gets clear what I mean.